# Divergence test for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine the convergence of
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$$

I have no idea what test I should use any hint? I think is divergent, I was thinking using comparison test but don't know where to start. But for fun I got:

$(\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$ ~ 1 for large n. therefore, the series should be divergent. so I need to show that $a_n \gt b_n$ for some $b_n$  diverges. for all $n \in N$, we have
$(\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$ $\gt$ n. since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $n$ is divergent then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $(\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$ is divergent

Answer (score 1):

You should also have the test (insert name)
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \not= 0
$$
implies that $\sum a_n$ does not converge. So you just need to show this is true.

EDIT:

Let $b_n = (2n^2)^{1/n} - 1$. If we can show that $\exists \, N$ where $b_n < 1$ for all $n > N$, then we have shown the sum converges.

Claim 1: $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$. (Show this.)

Claim 2: $\exists N$ such that $b_n < 1$ for all $n \ge N$ (this follows from Claim 1. Why?)

We can then split the sum into
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} b_n^n + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} b_n^n
$$
The first term is finite (denote it $L_1$), the second term, the $b_n < 1$. Let $\delta < 1$ be bound on these $b_n$ then we can bound the second term by
$$
\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} b_n^n \le \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \delta^n = L_2
$$
Which is a geometric series (hence finite). This proves the sequence converges.

Comment: little bite more hint...so i cant use $\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$ $\gt$ n? or $\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$ ~1

Comment: You absolutely could if you could show that those inequalities were true (note: this would imply the divergent test, since both of those limits would not converge to 0)

Comment: sorry i was trying to use comparison test, but i can use divergent test..so how would i show that is inequalities?

Comment: like this.. there exists $n_o$ $\in N$ s.t $\vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \vert (\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$ $\lt$ $\epsilon$ for all m,n $\in$ N with m $\gt$n $\gt$$n_o$?

Comment: I will edit the answer to be more helpful.